# Mysql table export as a single row Id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I try to make a pdf export, but i need to get only one row data, How i can make export only one unique id data. I tried many ways nothing works. I'm using TCPDF plugin for exporting, working fine with export all table data. I added a Id link on every buttton `export-pdf.php?view='.$row['id'].` I' can't understand how get this done. I try to make exporting inside a single file called `export-pdf.php`. any help greatly appreciate.

```
<?php  
 function fetch_data()  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "unibab");  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sites ORDER BY Id ASC";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
      print_r($row["register_date"]);   
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {       
      $output .= '<tr>   
                          <td>'.$row["Id"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["sitename"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["register_date"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>
                          <td><a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"  href= "export-pdf.php?export='.$row['Id'].'">Export</a></td>    
                     </tr>  
                     ';  
 }  
 return $output;  
}  
 if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {  
      require_once('pdf/tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
     
           <tr>  
                <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                <th width="45%">Designation</th>  
                <th width="10%">Age</th>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $obj_pdf->Output('sample.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>  

                          <tr>  
                               <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                               <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                               <th width="45%">Designation</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Age</th>
                               <th width="10%">Export</th>    
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     echo fetch_data();  
                     ?>  
           
                     <form method="post">  
                          <input type="submit" name="export" class="btn btn-danger" value="Create PDF" />  
                     </form>
```

Comment: I don't see where you look at your `view` parameter to decide which row to retrieve. You need to pass that into your `fetch_data()` function and put it into the query. You will then only get one row, so there's no need for the `while()` loop.

Comment: can you answer that more detailed.

Comment: updated qustion @droopsnoot

Comment: First, retrieve the "view" parameter from your URL query string into a variable. Next, change your `fetch_data()` to accept that variable as a parameter, then include that variable in your query using a prepared statement. Those steps should change your code to retrieve only the row that you want to see.